# Redux Devtools not showing up in React Native remote debugging

Tags: react-native, redux-toolkit

I can't set my redux store properly with react native.
I can't use redux dev tools when im debugging remotely.
Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redux tools will not work with the react-native directly, it needs additional changes but you can use [react-native-debugger](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger)

this provides the tools necessary without additional setup,